# push big view style

Tags: android, android-studio

Quisiera que los mensajes push tengan varias lineas pero no consigo que salga este es el codigo que uso.

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que hay un mal entendido, estas creando una notificación [**BigTextStyle**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html) por lo tanto tu notificación, se muestra en multilineas.

Cuando la recibes se debe mostrar de esta forma, el titulo y una linea de la descripción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando la expandes ya puedes ver la información en varias lineas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mismo sucede con la notificación [**BigPictureStyle**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle.html), se muestra el título y una sola línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al expandirla puedes ver el detalle y completamente la foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]